# How to correctly deal with a changing property of a class?

Tags: python, class

I have the class below where a method changes its property. However, I need the original unaltered property. What's the idiomatic way to do this?

The class describes a Borrower. The borrower has a property called PMT. this is the amortized value of the borrower. It is calculated from the present value. However, the borrower has a method which applies interest. This changes the present value, which in turn changes the PMT. I need to original PMT after I have applied the interest. What's the best way to get around it.
Heres the sample of the code

```
import numpy as np

class Borrower:
    def __init__(self, present_value, term, rate):
        self.present_value = present_value
        self.term = term
        self.rate = rate

    def pmt(self):
        return -np.pmt(self.rate/12, self.term, self.present_value)

    def apply_interest(self):
        self.present_value *= 1 + self.rate
```

Heres the problem:

```
b = Borrower(1000, 12, 0.1)
b.pmt()  # 87.91
b.apply_interest()
b.pmt()  # 96.70  I need 87.91 here!
```

Should I create a Borrower with an initial pmt like this?

```
class Borrower:
    def __init__(self, present_value, term, rate):
        self.present_value = present_value
        self.term = term
        self.rate = rate
        self.init_pmt = self.pmt()
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  If you need to save a value, just do it in the usual way: put it into a variable.

Comment: "Should I create a Borrower with an initial pmt like this?" That's what I would do

Comment: I definitely would go as @JETM says